# How does $\langle v , e_j\rangle = 0 \implies v =0$ implies $v \in \operatorname{span}(e_j)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

> How does $\langle v , e_j\rangle = 0 \implies v =0$ implies $v \in \operatorname{span}(e_j)$?

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Some books define an orthonormal basis as one that is in the title.

I am using the standard linear algebra definition, that is, an orthonormal basis is one that is a basis and orthonomal in the linear algebra (finite-dim) sense (every element in $H$ is a linear (possibly countably infinite) combination of $(e_k)$)

I am reading a proof where you are required to show $(w_k)$ is an orthonomal basis. Instead of showing $\forall h \in H, \exists c_j \in \Bbb F$ (F is the field, I forget, but is $\Bbb F$ always taken to be $\Bbb C$ in a Hilbert space?) such that $h = \sum c_j w_J$, they argue that if $\langle h,w_j \rangle = 0, \forall j \implies  h =0$ then that is sufficient.

Is it because by the orthogonal decamp, we get $h - \sum c_j w_j =0$? That is the above shows the orthongal component of $h$ is $0$, meaning $h = \sum c_j w_j =0$?

Comment: I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens you got any clue why it does that?

Comment: @ZelosMalum Because <, > are intended to be inequality symbols, and \langle, \rangle are meant to be angle-brackets. <, > are not intended to be used as angle-brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition seems to be correct, but I'll provide a few extra details.

The statement, that $\langle h,w_j\rangle=0$ for all $j$ implies that $h=0$ is enough to guarantee that the vectors $w_j$ span $H$.

Let $h$ be any element.  Then, $h-\sum\frac{\langle h,w_j\rangle}{\langle w_j,w_j\rangle} w_j$ has zero inner product with all $w_j$'s.  Then, by the condition, $h-\sum\frac{\langle h,w_j\rangle}{\langle w_j,w_j\rangle} w_j$ must be $0$, so $h=\sum\frac{\langle h,w_j\rangle}{\langle w_j,w_j\rangle} w_j$ and must be in the span.

It may be easier to think about this in terms of contradiction, if $h$ were not in the span, then $h-\sum\frac{\langle h,w_j\rangle}{\langle w_j,w_j\rangle} w_j$ would not be $0$, but $h-\sum\frac{\langle h,w_j\rangle}{\langle w_j,w_j\rangle} w_j$ would have $0$ inner product with all the $w_j$'s

Comment: Is the field thing correct? Because no books even mention it…( that I use).

Comment: (Wikipedia)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space] states that Hilbert spaces have a field of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.  One could conceivably work over other fields, by adapting the definitions appropriately.